# Layout with particular position of elements

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I have this layout.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp">
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp">
         <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/list_linearLayout">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <!--  titre food -->
                <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/souscarte_element_titleT"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>

                 <!-- description food -->          
                <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"
                    android:id="@+id/souscarte_element_descT"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- promo food -->
             <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/souscarte_element_promoT"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/souscarte_element_prixT"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
            <!--  price food -->
             <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:id="@+id/souscarte_element_prixT"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

The render of this is here : 
[image]

The problem is on the red frame (on the picture): when I have a big content (a lot of words) the second price (in bottom) put himself to the bottom and the text comes between the 1st price and the 2nd..

I would like to know how make it just stay in bottom of 1st price, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this.
hope this will helpful for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="17dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="17dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="5dip" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/list_linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.2"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/souscarte_element_titleT"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/souscarte_element_descT"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/souscarte_element_promoT"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/souscarte_element_prixT"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingRight="5dp"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: thats great Sangram! Thank you, The problem now is if the number is >10000 the "€" symbol comes down.. But I changed the weight of he 2 Layouts and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You have set `layout_align_parent_bottom="true"` for the second price, that is why it stays fixed to the bottom. Change this to `layout_below="@+id/souscarte_element_promoT"`.

Note that RelativeLayout allows its children to overlap, so it will draw children on top of other children if you aren't careful abotu how you arrange the children.

Comment: yes but when I do it the 2nd price comes on the bottom of the 1st price but it overwrite the text description..

Comment: As I said, RelativeLayout lets children overlap. You can set the description to have `layout_toLeftOf=@+id/souscarte_element_prixT`.

Answer (score 0):

You could nest two layouts inside the main layout...

One for the texts, and the other one for the prices

Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout       <!--For the texts-->
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView >
        <TextView >

    </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout <!--For the prices-->
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView >
        <TextView >

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather hard thing to achieve as TextView doesn't provide this feature.

However, it's still possible.

You can extend TextView and when it's supposed to show the text (not sure in which method), you can measure the last 2 lines of text (maybe using [Paint.measureText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#measureText%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20int,%20int%29)), in order to know where to place the price textView.

I say 2 because the first one would give you the Y coordinate, and the last one would tell you if it would wrap in case you put the textview, so that you will need to add extra to the Y coordinate.

Another possible solution is to put the price as a text inside the description TextView. In this solution you would also need to check the last line so that you could know if you need to create a new line or use the current one, and you need to know how many spaces to put.

Anyway, as others have mentioned, an easy way would be to simply always put the price below the text.